# Submittable HTML5 Web Component

Tags: polymer-1.0, web-component

How do I create a form-submittable web component?

Background:
I have a customer-picker component that is basically a text input plus a tiny button to the right of the text box plus a dialog that pops up when the button is clicked. It is used in the same way as one might use an html select.

This component is used as part of an html form that is submitted in the old fashioned (non-ajax) kind of way. The actual html input is encapsulated privately inside of the customer-picker component.

Problem:
The text input's value is not submitted

I guess I can understand why this is. I suppose this is the desired behavior (otherwise we are breaking encapsulation).

So with all that said, how do I create a submittable web component?

For example, suppose I have a form like this:

```
<form action="action.jsp">
    <input name="date-start"/>
    <input name="date-end"/>
    <input name="name-first"/>
    <input name="name-last"/>
</form>
```

that gets submitted like this:

`action.jsp?date-start=2016-06-01&date-end=2016-06-30&name-first=Joe&name-last=Smith`

I would like to create the same form using components like this:

```
<form action="action.jsp">
    <date-range name="date">
    <full-name name="name">
</form>
```

that gets submitted exactly the same way as the example above:

`action.jsp?date-start=2016-06-01&date-end=2016-06-30&name-first=Joe&name-last=Smith`

I am aware of iron-form. But this solution has some problems.

For one, it does not emulate native form submission very well. In a normal html form, when you submit, the current page is automatically replaced by whatever is returned by the action URL. This doesn't seem to happen with iron-form.

Second. It only allows your component to contribute a *single* value to the submitted data. In the above mentioned date-range example, I would like *two* values to be submitted for one component.

Comment: You should be able to use any input-type of web component in an HTML form as long as you've added `is="iron-form"`, as seen in the [`iron-form` demo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/blob/master/demo/index.html#L119-L128). We might be able to better help you if you provide a relevant sample of your code.

Comment: I am aware that iron-form is available. But this solution has some problems. For one, it does not emulate native form submission very well. In a normal html form, when you submit, the current page is automatically replaced by whatever is returned by the action URL. This doesn't seem to happen with iron-form. Second. It only allows your component to contribute a single value to the submitted data. In the example I gave each component contributes two values to the submitted data.

The idea is to take an existing form and update it to use components without having to redo a lot of other code.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it only allows your component to contribute a single value"? If you could provide a code sample, I'd be able better assist you (including explaining certain behaviors and possible solutions).

Comment: The date-range component, if i'm not to break existing server-side code, should cause *two* separate parameters to be added to the submitted data:

?d1=2016-06-01&d2=2016-06-30

But the iron-form only allows each contained element to contribute a single value. So I must write code, inside the date-range component, that concatenates the two values into a single value. Something like this:

?date-range=2016-06-01|2016-06-30

Then I must change my server-side code to parse/split the value into again.